# Modelling rates or levels in state transition model

Tags: time-series, hidden-markov-model, state-space-models

**Q:** Suppose I'm modeling the transition of customers from one state to another. Is it better to model the time series of transition *rates* directly or implicitly as a time-varying parameter in a model of the *levels* of customers in each state? Does it matter?

**Definitions:** Let $Y_t$ and $X_t$ represent the number of customers in each of two states at time $t$, with transition probability $p_t \equiv \frac{Y_t}{X_{t-1}}$.

**Model 1:** $\mathrm{Logit}(p_t) \sim \mathrm{SARIMA}(0,1,0)\times(1,0,0)_{12}$ (or any standard univariate time series model which can capture seasonality). Then with forecasts of $X_t$, I can produce a forecast $\widehat{Y_{t+h|t}} \equiv \widehat{p_{t+h|t}}\widehat{X_{t+h|t}}$

**Model 2:**

\begin{align}
\log(Y_t) &= p_t \log(X_{t-1}) + \epsilon_t \\
\mathrm{Logit}(p_t) &\sim \mathrm{SARIMA}(0,1,0)\times(1,0,0)_{12}
\end{align}

Here, I believe we could put this into state-space form, get estimates for the $p_t$ and get forecasts for the $Y_t$. This approach seems more involved with multiple sources of noise (one for transition equation and one for observation equation). But it does look like it could generalize to multiple states more easily that Model 1.

**Afterthoughts:** Modeling customer movement through multiple states seems like it would be such a common problem. There has to be a best-practices approach, right? I've briefly looked into R's `msm` package. Not sure how well that handles forecasting or aggregate customers in states (as opposed to individuals). `dlm` looks to be R's standard state-space modelling package. That seems like a good approach here. But then again, if I remember right, a state-space model requires linear equations with multivariate normal disturbances, which is a big constraint when trying to model transition rates. Anyway, I just seem to be struggling around how to think about this in the right away. Can someone help straighten me out?